# Groovy AST Transformation - replace method

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to replace a method of a class using AST transformations.

I first check to see if the method exists and then remove it ([based on this](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Can-I-remove-methods-in-an-AST-transformation-td369716.html)).

```
MethodNode methodNode = parentClass.getMethod(methodName, Parameter.EMPTY_ARRAY)
if (methodNode != null) {
     parentClass.getMethods().remove(methodNode)
}
```

I see the size change on the collection, but the method is still accessible on the class node.

After removing the method I would then like to add a new one of the same name:

```
parentClass.addMethod(newMethodNode)
```

However, this causes the following error:

```
 Repetitive method name/signature for method 'grails.plugin.Bar getBar()' in class 'grails.plugin.Foo'.
```

What is the correct way to do this?

**Update:**
Since all I was intending to do was replace existing functionality of the method, I instead created a new [block statement](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/stmt/BlockStatement.html) and set this on the existing method using `methodNode.setCode(statement)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're trying to do is to wrap a method with some other stuff? Here's an example of wrapping a method in a try/finally.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.*

methodNode.setCode(methodThatCreatesAst(methodNode.getCode()))

def methodThatCreatesAst(Statement statementToWrap) {
  BlockStatement methodBody = new BlockStatement()

  methodBody.addStatement(new TryCatchStatement(
    // try
    statementToWrap,
    // finally
    new ExpressionStatement(
      new MethodCallExpression(
        "myVar", "myMethod", new ArgumentListExpression()
      )
    )
  ))

  return methodBody
}
```

Other than that I'm not able to help since I've never actually attempted to remove a method before :)

Comment: I'm not trying to just wrap it, but replace the entire body of the method with new functionality. Thanks for the suggestion.