# AST Transformation to wrap entire method body in a closure

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to do something rather simple. I would like to wrap the whole method code into an additional closure block that would measure the execution time. Right now I'm getting a really not helpful error message:

```
Error:Groovyc: NPE while processing Test.groovy
```

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target([ElementType.METHOD])
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(["WithTimingASTTransformation"])
public @interface WithTiming {
}
```

My wrapping closure:

```
class Benchmark {
    static def measureTime(Closure cl) {
        def start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        def result = cl()
        def time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
        println "it took $time"
        result
    }
}
```

My Transformation:

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
class WithTimingASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {
    @Override
    void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
        MethodNode method = astNodes[1]
        method.code = wrap(method)
    }

    private Statement wrap(MethodNode method) {
        def newBlock = new BlockStatement()
        newBlock.addStatement(
                new ExpressionStatement(
                        new StaticMethodCallExpression(
                                new ClassNode(Benchmark),
                                'measureTime',
                                new ArgumentListExpression(
                                        new ClosureExpression(new Parameter[0], method.code)
                                ))))
        newBlock
    }
}
```

I'm really stuck here and don't know how can I debug the problem.

There is an answer on a similar topic (wrapping whole method body into a try/catch block [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28307394/1788766)). This works fine but my case is slightly different.

Comment: Have you tried debugging into the transformation during your unit test (the test for your transformation) to see where the NPE is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

In my case similar NPE was coming from:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.ClosureWriter.createClosureClass(ClosureWriter.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.ClosureWriter.getOrAddClosureClass(ClosureWriter.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.ClosureWriter.writeClosure(ClosureWriter.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClosureExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:673)
```

Whereas:

```
    if (parameters == null || expression.getVariableScope() == null) {
        parameters = Parameter.EMPTY_ARRAY;
    } else if (parameters.length == 0) {
        // let's create a default 'it' parameter
        Parameter it = new Parameter(ClassHelper.OBJECT_TYPE, "it", ConstantExpression.NULL);
        parameters = new Parameter[]{it};
        Variable ref = expression.getVariableScope().getDeclaredVariable("it");
        if (ref != null) it.setClosureSharedVariable(ref.isClosureSharedVariable());
    }
```

and line 194 (as of https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/commit/a52d0d3c5dd1cbb342992d36235171718a563c8b) is:

```
Variable ref = expression.getVariableScope().getDeclaredVariable("it");
```

Thus you need to define a VariableScope for your ClosureExpression. I had to add tracing into org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClosureWriter to find this, because there is an issue with exception display on stage of Class Generation - both in IntelliJ Idea and in Groovy Console - it does not show proper lines of code.

Furthermore, I think that either ClosureWriter or ClosureExpression constructor can be fixed to work aligned by default - without this NPE. I will possibly submit an issue to Groovy Jira for this.

Now I am able to inject closure expression in my code. But struggling to call this closure.

Getting:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.a9ae0b01f0ffc.VSMSGEN.implementation.T_visa_recon_generator$_convert_vts_log_to_ctf_closure2.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, after some iterations my method-wrapping AST looks like this:

```
BlockStatement bs = new BlockStatement()
ClosureExpression closureExp = new ClosureExpression( methodNode.parameters, methodNode.code )
closureExp.variableScope = new VariableScope() // <- this does the trick!
bs.addStatement new ExpressionStatement( new StaticMethodCallExpression( new ClassNode( TransactionUtil ), 'wrap', new ArgumentListExpression( closureExp ) ) )
methodNode.code = bs
```

The line `closureExp.variableScope = new VariableScope()` avoids the NPE in `ClosureWriter.java:194` and the whole thing runs like a charm!

Hope it helps someone...